# alignment in applet

Tags: java, applet

how can we align the variois interface component(such as label, textfield, button) in applet??

As for instance i want 4 label and a button in an applet, in which all the component should be in different line?? how can we do it??

Answer (score 0):

Use Layout Managers in java to align components depends on various order. for reference try this [link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

and for your own position there is an layout manager call null layout ([example](http://www.java.happycodings.com/Java_AWT/code19.html))